# Lambda Expression for "not in"?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, lambda

I have a `detailcollection` collection in which every detail has

```
code, price, name
```

And a string with some codes

```
string codes = "1,2,3";
```

I know I can get an array using `string.Split()`

```
string[] codesarray = codes.Split(',');
```

But how can I get products not in `codes`?

```
// the idea I have, but I would not like to have a loop
for (int i = 0; i < codesarray.Length; i++)
{
    detailcollection.Where(x => x.ope_idsku == codesarray[i])
}
```

I would like something like:

```
detailcollection.Where(x => x.ope_idsku not in (codesarray))
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Selected details collection items which ids are not in `codesarray`:

```
detailcollection.Where (x=> !codesarray.Contains(x.ope_idsku))
```