# implementing "where in" clause in Lambda?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have a expression which is returning me Ids:

```
var UserNotificationIds = _notificationBidderRepos.All(u => u.BidderId == BidderId).Select(n =>n.BidderId);
```

Another structure has Notifications and requirement is to filter notifications for which Id is provided in `UserNotificationIds`

```
var AllNotifications = _notificationRepos.All(n => n.ExpiresAt > DateTime.UtcNow).ToList();
```

I m trying the following code to query all Notifications but not getting how to impement "where in" in my expression.

Please help

Comment: You samples look strange - `All` returns `bool` - so not sure how you `Select` on result...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is selecting based off of 1 id

```
selectAll.where(x => x.id == varId)
```

If you pass in multiple ids then you need to use .Contains().

```
selectAll.where(x => idList.contains(x.id))
```

Comment: Thanks @Dassina, 2nd worked for me. Can you please also guide how I can change it to "not in" ? Much appreciate your help

Comment: Use Except.  Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640259/linq-select-where-object-does-not-contain-items-from-list

Comment: Alternatively

    selectAll.where(x => !idList.contains(x.id))

Reference:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574952/lambda-expression-for-not-in

Answer (score 3):

It seems you need [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var AllNotifications = _notificationRepos.Where(n => n.ExpiresAt > DateTime.UtcNow 
                               && UserNotificationIds.Contains(n.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: +1. Note that original sample probably will not compile as [All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Contains" or "Join" approach for "where in" filtering.  Code sample and detail in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40795965/4418611)